# How to trigger Update-Database on a DbContext in a referenced assembly (NuGet package)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Using the Package Manager Console I can run a command similar to the following one

```
Update-Database -ProjectName: My.Project.Data
```

The command triggers migrations on `MyDbContext` defined within the project `My.Project.Data` located in the currently open solution. Good.

Now the project `My.Project.Data` resides in the same solution with project `My.Project.Mvc`. The problem is, `My.Project.Mvc` uses two db contexts. One that we already covered and another one defined within project `Core.Project.Data` - this one is built as a NuGet package which is then referenced by `My.Project.Mvc`. The diagram below should make it clear:

```
MySolution
├┬ My.Project.Mvc
│├─ references: My.Project.Data (in the same solution)
│└─ references: Core.Project.Data (NuGet)
└─ My.Project.Data [MyDbContext]

CoreSolution
└─ Core.Project.Data [CoreDbContext]
```

The question is, how can I trigger the migrations for the `CoreDbContext` from the Package Manager Console of `MySolution`. If I try to run `Update-Database -ProjectName: Core.Project.Data` I get the error:

```
Get-Project : Project 'Core.Project.Data' is not found.
```

**Update:** Using the migrate.exe instead is not an option.

Comment: Could be an issue with your Nuget package? https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/2884

Comment: @SteveGreene, thx for the link. However I have tried to restart the PC, clean the solution, rebuild the solution ... none of that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [document](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Update-Database) update-database does not support dll.

You can execute EF migration tool from commandline, or add it in VS menu for conveniences.

```
migrate.exe Core.Project.Data.dll /startupConfigurationFile=Core.Project.Data.dll.config
```

or change `/startupConfigurationFile` to `/connectionString=your-connection-string`

Comment: Thank you, it is good point (+1), however I am aware of the migrate.exe and I was looking for a way how to avoid it. Update-Database is much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

When migrations are first enabled by `Enable-Migration`, a `Configuration.cs` file will be added to the project. If this file exists for `Core.Project.Data`, tell Entity Framework to use this config:

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName Core.Project.Data.Migrations.Configuration -ProjectName Core.Project.Data
```

Comment: I guess you meant the `ConfigurationTypeName` (not `Configuration`) option, right? Unfortunately it does not help anyhow as the command tries to locate the given type in the current assembly ...

Comment: Even if you combine it with `-ProjectName` to point to the other assembly? I edited my answer...

Comment: Yes, of course, I have already tried to specify the `-ProjectName` but in such case I run into the error message described in my question. Specifying the `-ConfigurationTypeName` is fine but first you need to be able to locate the project. And that is what the Update-Database command fails at.

Comment: Not working anymore (I'm using VS 2019 and .NET Core 2.2): 
Update-Database : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConfigurationTypeName'.

Comment: For the new .NET Core tools update-database command we are supposed to use the -context parameter, but it still doesn't work as it tries to locate the dbcontext in the current assembly and not in the one referenced.